# Set of functions that are instances in a common way

Tags: class, haskell, default, subclassing, repeat

I'm pretty new to haskell and I think I'm falling into some OO traps. Here's a sketch of a structure (simplified) that I'm having trouble implementing:

- A concept of an Observable that acts on a list of samples (Int) to produce a result (Int)

  - A concept SimpleObservable that achieves the result using a certain pattern (while there will be Observables that do it other ways), e.g. something like an average
- A function instance, e.g. one that's just an average times a constant

My first thought was to use a subclass; something like (the below is kinda contrived but hopefully gets the idea across)

```
class Observable a where
  estimate :: a -> [Int] -> Int

class (Observable a) => SimpleObservable a where
  compute :: a -> Int -> Int
  simpleEstimate :: a -> [Int] -> Int
  simpleEstimate obs list = sum $ map compute list

data AveConst = AveConst Int

instance Observable AveConst where
  estimate = simpleEstimate

instance SimpleObservable AveConst  where
  compute (AveConst c) x = c * x
```

However, even if something like the above compiles it's ugly. Googling tells me `DefaultSignatures` might help in that I don't have to do `estimate = simpleEstimate` for each instance but from discussions around it it seems doing it this way would be an antipattern.

Another option would be to have no subclass, but something like (with the same `Observable` class):

```
data AveConst = AveConst Int

instance Observable AveConst where
  estimate (AveConst c) list = sum $ map (*c) list
```

But this way I'm not sure how to reuse the pattern; each `Observable` has to contain the complete `estimate` definition and there will be code repetition.

A third way is a type with a function field:

```
data SimpleObservable = SimpleObservable {
  compute :: [Int] -> Int
} 

instance Observable SimpleObservable where
  estimate obs list =
    sum $ map (compute obs) list

aveConst :: Int -> SimpleObservable
aveConst c = SimpleObservable {
  compute = (*c)
}
```

But I'm not sure this is idiomatic either. Any advice?

Comment: "Even if the above compiles, it's ugly." I have bad news: it's ugly, *and* it doesn't compile.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what is the problem you are trying to solve. As a very rough intuition, consider Haskell typeclasses as something that can be used to achieve OOP function overloading. Do you need that for your problem? As a general thumb rule, if you have only one instance, this is like having one overload, so you don't really need typeclasses to begin with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I propose going even simpler:

```
type Observable = [Int] -> Int
```

Then, an averaging observable is:

```
average :: Observable
average ns = sum ns `div` length ns
```

If your `Observable` needs some data inside -- say, a constant to multiply by -- no problem; that's what closures are for. For example:

```
sumTimesConst :: Int -> Observable
sumTimesConst c = sum . map (c*)
```

You can abstract over the construction of `Observable`s without trouble; e.g. if you want a `SimpleObservable` which only looks at elements, and then sums, you can:

```
type SimpleObservable = Int -> Int

timesConst :: Int -> SimpleObservable
timesConst = (*)

liftSimple :: SimpleObservable -> Observable
liftSimple f = sum . map f
```

Then `liftSimple . timesConst` is another perfectly fine way to spell `sumTimesConst`.

...but honestly, I'd feel dirty doing *any* of the above things. `sum . map (c*)` is a perfectly readable expression without introducing a questionable new name for its type.

Comment: Good points! But the last paragraph is only true because this is a simplified sketch of the actual problem.

Comment: I guess my only problem with this is: if I mistakenly use as an observable a function with the right signature but which was never intended as an observable the compiler won't know. Or is this not a good way to think?

Comment: @jorgen It's a fine way to think. In such cases you can use a `newtype` wrapper to distinguish between `Observable` and `[Int] -> Int`; but exercise taste -- too many `newtype`s can be just as bad as too few.

Answer (score 3):

I do not fully understand the question yet but I'll edit this answer as I learn more.

Something which acts on a list and produces a result can simply be a function. The interface (that is, the type) of this function can be `[a] -> b`. This says the function accepts a list of elements of some type and returns a result of a possibly different type.

Now, lets invent a small problem as an example. I want to take a list of lists, some function on lists which produces a number, apply this function to every list, and return the average of the numbers.

```
average :: (Fractional b) => ([a] -> b) -> [[a]] -> b
average f xs = sum (fmap f xs) / genericLength xs
```

For example, `average genericLength` will tell me the average length of the sub-lists. I do not need to define any type classes or new types. Simply, I use the function type `[a] -> b` for those functions which map a list to some result.

Comment: Thanks! But the crux of the problem (maybe not expressed properly in the OP) is that there will be several functions, `SimpleObservable`s, (of which `aveConst` in the OP is one example) that are `Observable`s in similar but different ways and I want to avoid code repetition between these. In a way the "outer" functionality (average in the example) will be common but the "inner" will not (multiplication of constant in example). Also, importantly, there will be other kinds of `Observable`s that have a different "outer" structure, i.e. not be `SimpleObservable`s.

Comment: Maybe spend more time with Haskell before trying to implement sophisticated abstractions, jorgen. I am having a difficult time understanding what you want to achieve. Many functions have the type `[a] -> b` for various choices of `a` and `b`. `genericLength` is just one such function if we choose `b` to be some `Fractional` type.

Comment: In my opinion this is not very sophisticated, erisco. As stated the OP is a simplified sketch of the actual problem, which is why it's a bit contrived and seems to have a much simpler solution as you point out.

Comment: You usually do not need to define new type classes. While common in OOP, it is uncommon in FP. What I mean is that you may more clearly see how to actualise your ideas if you spend more time with the basics of Haskell. I am not sure what an `Observable` is supposed to be, unless it is like that in C#, in which case there are already libraries which can help you depending on what specifically you need.

Comment: Hm, I guess I thought of the `Observable` class as an organising principle; every time I'd want to write an observable the compiler will enforce that it has a function of the right type. Of course it will also complain if I try to use any function with the wrong signature in an "observable-context," with a different warning. You may be right, maybe a new class is not the answer and doesn't give any more type safety.